# Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows-7

So I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my pc but I'm currently using Windows 7 as my default OS. How do I revert back to Ubuntu?

Comment: We'll need more info. How did you install Ubuntu and Windows, and in what order? What partitions have you kept, and what installation options, especially those related to partitioning, GRUB, a bootloader, or MBR, have you set?

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info). This will give us information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to set the default.  You can set it to a specified number or a name in `/etc/default/grub`:

There is an entry at the top that says `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`, or some other number.  Zero means the first menu entry will be the default, usually Ubuntu or whatever distro installed this grub.  You can change that number to a different one.

You can also set it to a specific name, so that the numerical order won't matter - but it needs to be the exact name, such as: `GRUB_DEFAULT="Microsoft Windows XP Professional (on /dev/sda1)"`

You can set it so the last chosen OS becomes the default until you choose a new one, by adding this line below the GRUB_DEFAULT setting:  `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true`

From [Grub2 - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2):

Saving an OS can be achieved by running sudo grub-set-default if GRUB_DEFAULT=saved is set in /etc/default/grub. It may also be saved if GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true is also set in /etc/default/grub. In this case, the default OS remains until a new OS is manually selected from the GRUB 2 menu or the grub-set-default command is executed.